# How to fix "import com.dyuproject cannot be resolved" error

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers, protostuff

I'm fairly new to Java and especially new to Maven and specifically the protostuff project ([protostuff website](http://www.protostuff.io/)). I need to use protostuff to serialize/deserialize XML to google's protobuf format. I tried using the [protobuf-java-format](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-java-format/) package, but there's a documented error in deserialization that is a show-stopper for me ([issue 37](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-java-format/issues/detail?id=37)).

So far I've done the following:

1. Downloaded protostuff-1.3.1 & extracted it.
2. Ran `mvn integration-test`, `mvn install` and `mvn package`and all steps succeeded.
3. I then created a new maven project and included a proto as described [here](http://www.protostuff.io/documentation/compiler-maven/)
4. I then modified my pom.xml and ran `protostuff:compile` on the proto as described in the [aforementioned link](http://www.protostuff.io/documentation/compiler-maven/), generating the following Person.java file

   ```
   // Generated by http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/ ... DO NOT EDIT!
   // Generated from foo.proto

   package com.example.foo;

   import java.io.Externalizable;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.ObjectInput;
   import java.io.ObjectOutput;

   import com.dyuproject.protostuff.ByteString;
   import com.dyuproject.protostuff.GraphIOUtil;
   import com.dyuproject.protostuff.Input;
   import com.dyuproject.protostuff.Message;
   import com.dyuproject.protostuff.Output;
   import com.dyuproject.protostuff.Schema;
   import com.dyuproject.protostuff.UninitializedMessageException;

   public final class Person implements Externalizable, Message<Person>, Schema<Person>
   {
       public enum Gender implements com.dyuproject.protostuff.EnumLite<Gender>
       {
           MALE(1),
           FEMALE(2);

           public final int number;

           private Gender (int number)
           {
               this.number = number;
           }

           public int getNumber()
           {
               return number;
           }

           public static Gender valueOf(int number)
           {
               switch(number) 
               {
                   case 1: return MALE;
                   case 2: return FEMALE;
                   default: return null;
               }
           }
       }


       public static Schema<Person> getSchema()
       {
           return DEFAULT_INSTANCE;
       }

       public static Person getDefaultInstance()
       {
           return DEFAULT_INSTANCE;
       }

       static final Person DEFAULT_INSTANCE = new Person();

       static final String DEFAULT_MOTTO = ByteString.stringDefaultValue("When the cat is away, the mouse is alone!");
       static final Gender DEFAULT_GENDER = Gender.MALE;

       private Integer id;
       private String name;
       private String motto = DEFAULT_MOTTO;
       private Gender gender;

       public Person()
       {

       }

       public Person(
           Integer id
       )
       {
           this.id = id;
       }

       // getters and setters

       // id

       public Integer getId()
       {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId(Integer id)
       {
           this.id = id;
       }

       // name

       public String getName()
       {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name)
       {
           this.name = name;
       }

       // motto

       public String getMotto()
       {
           return motto;
       }

       public void setMotto(String motto)
       {
           this.motto = motto;
       }

       // gender

       public Gender getGender()
       {
           return gender == null ? Gender.MALE : gender;
       }

       public void setGender(Gender gender)
       {
           this.gender = gender;
       }

       // java serialization

       public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException
       {
           GraphIOUtil.mergeDelimitedFrom(in, this, this);
       }

       public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException
       {
           GraphIOUtil.writeDelimitedTo(out, this, this);
       }

       // message method

       public Schema<Person> cachedSchema()
       {
           return this;
       }

       // schema methods

       public Person newMessage()
       {
           return new Person();
       }

       public Class<Person> typeClass()
       {
           return Person.class;
       }

       public String messageName()
       {
           return Person.class.getSimpleName();
       }

       public String messageFullName()
       {
           return Person.class.getName();
       }

       public boolean isInitialized(Person message)
       {
           return 
               message.id != null;
       }

       public void mergeFrom(Input input, Person message) throws IOException
       {
           for(int number = input.readFieldNumber(this);; number = input.readFieldNumber(this))
           {
               switch(number)
               {
                   case 0:
                       return;
                   case 1:
                       message.id = input.readInt32();
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       message.name = input.readString();
                       break;
                   case 3:
                       message.motto = input.readString();
                       break;
                   case 4:
                       message.gender = Gender.valueOf(input.readEnum());
                       break;
                   default:
                       input.handleUnknownField(number, this);
               }   
           }
       }


       public void writeTo(Output output, Person message) throws IOException
       {
           if(message.id == null)
               throw new UninitializedMessageException(message);
           output.writeInt32(1, message.id, false);

           if(message.name != null)
               output.writeString(2, message.name, false);

           if(message.motto != null && message.motto != DEFAULT_MOTTO)
               output.writeString(3, message.motto, false);

           if(message.gender != null)
                output.writeEnum(4, message.gender.number, false);
       }

       public String getFieldName(int number)
       {
           switch(number)
           {
               case 1: return "id";
               case 2: return "name";
               case 3: return "motto";
               case 4: return "gender";
               default: return null;
           }
       }

       public int getFieldNumber(String name)
       {
           final Integer number = __fieldMap.get(name);
           return number == null ? 0 : number.intValue();
       }

       private static final java.util.HashMap<String,Integer> __fieldMap = new java.util.HashMap<String,Integer>();
       static
       {
           __fieldMap.put("id", 1);
           __fieldMap.put("name", 2);
           __fieldMap.put("motto", 3);
           __fieldMap.put("gender", 4);
       }

   }
   ```

I'm building this whole project in Eclipse (Luna release) and it gives the error "import com.dyuproject cannot be resolved" for the above file. I don't understand why it gives the error or how to find/install the package so Eclipse can see it. Should Maven have built/provided that?

I'm running CentOS release 6.4 (Final) on a VirtualBox VM:

`uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 28 17:19:38 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using incompatible `protostuff-core` and `protostuff-maven-plugin` versions.

Starting from version 1.1, protostuff uses package `io.protostuff` instead of `com.dyuproject.protostuff`. Protostuff dependency version and protostuff maven plugin version should be equal (1.3.5 is the latest version).

[Here](https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff-examples/tree/master/hello-world) is an example of maven project that uses `protostuff-maven-plugin` for code generation.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for setting me straight and for updating protustuff.io and git.